# How to integrate PayPal API in React Native Expo without detaching or ejecting my project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, paypal, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to integrate **PayPal Api** with my **Expo** Project. I could not find any relevant solution about PayPal Api Integration. Please help!

I was able to successfully integrate **Stripe Api** in Expo project but I could not find any library or plugin for PayPal in Expo.

I tried the [react-native-paypal](https://github.com/MattFoley/react-native-paypal) library but it is not working with my Expo project.